# Confusing port entries in Auth log

Tags: firewall, ufw

I've found a lot of entries in my auth log....

```
Failed password for root from 59.45.175.12 port 59662 ssh2
```

(ip above not actual IP for security reasons)
Which I think is someone trying to hack in, this is not my problem, I can easily block the IP in UFW.

But, what I can't understand is the port "59962"  (this seems to change on each entry by the way)
I currently have UFW installed and running, as as far as I can see the port above (59962) is already blocked in UFW, so I don't undertand how the auth request is getting as far as SSH?

UFW as I understand it blocks all ports except those specifically allowed, the port above is not in my allowed list - unless I'm missing something...

Can someone explain please?

IcarusBop

Answer (score 0):

The port number that's being logged (`59962`) is the originating port on the *other* system (`59.45.175.12`). See `man 7 socket` for info on how sockets work.

Yes, it looks like you are being attacked. Look at the `fail2ban` package:

```
fail2ban - ban hosts that cause multiple authentication errors
```

Find the hostname of the other system via:

```
dig -x 59.45.175.12
```